# Does using new ReferenceType in a hibernate query affect performance?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have follow code in my java DAO class.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select new Question(q.qid, q.qtype) from Question q where q.qlang=:lang ");
```

1. Does using new object type in a hibernate query affect performance? In What way is it affected?
2. Over all code execution (be it the above java code or the sql query it gets converted into and then the assembly of the sql result in a `Question` object), does it increase or decrease the overall performance of the application?

Comment: This question would probably be better suited for the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) community: _"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers."_ While the question initially does contains database elements, Hibernate (and JPA) is a 3-rd party database abstraction layer that is not directly related to MySQL. Hence the recommendation to post in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @hot2use done..